# C# Traverse object hierarchy for execution of method

Tags: c#

I have a Case object that in itself contains a number of objects (see below), that again contains objects.

These objects can inherit from a BaseDto class, that implements the ValidateObject method, that executes a DataAnnotation validator on the current object, thus returning with validation errors, accumulated into a ValidationResult collection.

I would like to transform the following cluttered syntax, to something where I can traverse the object hierarchy of a given object, and for each of the objects (and its children!) that implements ValidateObject, execute it.

I'm feeling kinda stuck at the moment, so I would be grateful for any ideas.

```
cCase.ValidateObject() &
cCase.Object1.ValidateObject() &
cCase.Object2.ValidateObject() &
cCase.Object3.ValidateObject() &
cCase.Object3.ChildObject1.ValidateObject() &
cCase.Object3.ChildObject2.ValidateObject() &
cCase.Object3.ChildObject3.ValidateObject() &
cCase.Object3.ChildObject4.ValidateObject() &
cCase.Object3.ChildObject4.ChildChildObject1.ValidateObject() &
cCase.Object3.ChildObject5.ValidateObject() &
cCase.Object4.ValidateObject() &
cCase.Object4.ChildObject6.ValidateObject();
```

Comment: Why not have the implementation of ValidateObject for each class also run ValidateObject for all of the child objects it contains?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all fields, which inherit from a `BaseDto` class, using reflection:

```
public abstract class BaseDto
{
    public abstract bool ValidateObject();
}

// Sample class without nested fields, requiring validation.
public class Case2 : BaseDto
{
    public override bool ValidateObject()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Validated: " + ToString());
        return false;
    }
}

// Sample nested class with nested fields, requiring validation.
public class Case1 : BaseDto
{
    private Case2 Object1 = new Case2();
    private Case2 Object2 = new Case2();
    private Stream stream = new MemoryStream();

    public override bool ValidateObject()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Validated: " + ToString());
        return true;
    }
}

public class Case : BaseDto
{
    private Case1 Object1 = new Case1();
    private Case2 Object2 = new Case2();
    // don't touch this field
    private Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    private Case1 Object3 = new Case1();

    public override bool ValidateObject()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Validated: " + ToString());
        return true;
    }

    public bool ValidateAll()
    {
        if (!ValidateObject()) return false;
        return ValidateAll(this);
    }

    private bool ValidateAll(object o)
    {
        foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in o.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance |
               BindingFlags.NonPublic |
               BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            BaseDto current = fieldInfo.GetValue(o) as BaseDto;

            if(current != null)
            {
                bool result = current.ValidateObject();
                if(!result)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return ValidateAll(current);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Call `ValidateAll()` on root object. Inside it traverses all fields, which are derived from `BaseDto`, validates them and all fields inside them recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use extension methods like this:

```
public interface IValidatable
{
    bool ValidateObject();
}

public static class ValidateExtensions
{
    public static bool ValidateAll(this IValidatable item)
    {
        if (!item.ValidateObject())
            return false;

        const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
        var type = item.GetType();
        var props = type.GetProperties(flags).Select(x => x.GetValue(item));
        var fields = type.GetFields(flags).Select(x => x.GetValue(item));
        return props
            .Concat(fields)
            .OfType<IValidatable>()
            .Select(x => x.ValidateAll())
            .All(x => x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It would be cleaner to have each class in the hierarchy override `ValidateObject()` to validate its child objects:

```
public override bool ValidateObject()
{
    return base.ValidateObject() & 
        this.Object1.ValidateObject() &
        this.Object2.ValidateObject() &
        this.Object3.ValidateObject() &
        this.Object4.ValidateObject();
}
```

etc.  Then the client can just call `ValidateObject()` on the root object.